# Problem with PrepareStatement in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have created table with 3 fields language,country,install type. When I write a query to print the maximum occuring value in each of the field, I am getting a weird problem.Can anyone say the reason.Here is my code.

```
PreparedStatement ps1= null;
ps1 = conn.prepareStatement("desc Configuration");

ResultSet rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
while(rs1.next()) {

    System.out.print(rs1.getString(1)+":");

    PreparedStatement ps2= null;

    ps2 = conn.prepareStatement("select ? from Configuration c1 "+
                                "  group by language "+
                                "  having count(*) >= all " +
                                "     ( select count(*) from Configuration c2 "+
                                "         group by language )");

    ps2.setString(1,rs1.getString(1));

    ResultSet rs2=ps2.executeQuery();

    while(rs2.next())
        System.out.print(rs2.getString(1));

    System.out.println();
}
```

The output I am getting here is **language:language** But the output what I am expecting is
**language:english** like that. I am getting later output if i replace '?' with language in the prepare statement.But if i give the same with ? I am getting what ever I have given for ps2.setString.

Why is this happening. Any solutions?

Answer (score 5):

`?` in prepared statements is not a placeholder for textual substitution, it's a parameter, therefore its value is always interpreted as data, not as an arbitrary part of query syntax.

So, in this case the actual query being executed is an equivalent of `select 'language' from ...`.

If you need to substitute parts of the query other than data, you have to use concatenation (beware of SQL injections!):

```
ps2 = conn.prepareStatement("select " 
    + rs1.getString(1)
    + " from Configuration c1 group by language having count(*) >= all( select count(*)from Configuration c2 group by language )");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't set column names using a `PreparedStatement`. You can only set column values.

Instead of using this approach, you will have to build the sql yourself using concatenation, for example:

```
String sql = "select "+ rs1.getString(1) + " from Configuration c1 group by language having count(*) >= all( select count(*)from Configuration c2 group by language)";
```

Answer (score 1):

The '?' mark in ps2 is recognized as literal-string. Not as a column name.